# Python - Selenium Xpath to get content between first & 2nd h3 tags

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

**Structure:**

```
<h3>Description</h3>
<p>Para1</p>
<p>Para1</p>
<p>Para1</p>
<p>Para1</p>
<h3>Description2</h3>
<p>Para1</p>
<p>Para1</p>
<p>Para1</p>
<p>Para1</p>
```

Now i want to extract all `<p>` between first `<h3>` to second `<h3>`.
**Conditions:**

1. without using heading content check. Since Description2 `<h3>` is dynamic content and not a constant value.
2. `<h3>` sometimes will be `<h1>` or `<h2>` too...

Tried below generic code,

```
One way
$x("//*[starts-with(name(),'h')][starts-with(.,'Description')]/following-sibling::*[following-sibling::*[starts-with(name(),'h')][starts-with(.,'Description2')]]")

Another
$x("//*[preceding-sibling::*[starts-with(name(),'h')] = 'Description' and following-sibling::*[starts-with(name(),'h')] = 'Description2']")
```

How to query between contents without specifying Description & Description2 texts?

Comment: Two things: first, what does "sometimes will be or too..." mean? Second, are you trying to do it with pure xpath or can you actually use python libraries as well?

Comment: Are you using selenium? Then do this programatically. Any other surrounding html?

Comment: Yes. Only using Selenium with pure Xpath. Also there are some <div> surrounding.